# Graph theory proof regarding simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph with n>=2 nodes and minimal degree δ. Show that there is a spanning subgraph of G with minimal degree δ and at most δ(n-1) edges. I tried using induction but it didn't seem to be going anywhere, if anyone can help that will be great.

Comment: Your goal here is to delete as many edges from $G$ as possible while preserving the minimum degree. When can you delete an edge? What does the graph look like when it's no longer possible to delete any edges?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I believe you can delete an edge if it's not connected to any nod who's degree is δ, so after finishing with this process you can say that every edge is connected to at least one vertex with degree δ, so the total amount of edges cannot be over n*δ/2, which is always smaller than δ(n-1) when n>=2, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing all edges connecting vertices whose degree is higher than $\delta$ (edges are removed one by one), we obtain a graph $G'$ in which $V=X\cup Y$, the degree of each vertex of $X$ is equal to $\delta$, the degree of each vertex of $Y$ is higher than $\delta$. Hence $Y$ has no edges. Then $\delta|X|\geq |E(G')|$ (why?). It remains to consider two cases $|X|=n$ and $|X|<n$.