# A graph with minimal degree of $\delta$ has a subgraph with the same minimal degree and no more than $\delta(n-1)$ edges

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that $|V(G)>1$ and $\delta(G)=\delta$. Show that there is a subgraph of $G$ lets call him $G'$ such that $\delta(G')= \delta$ and $|E(G')|= \delta(n-1)$. Here $\delta(G)$ is the minimal degree of $G$, $V(G)$ is the set of vertices and $E(G)$ is the set of edges of $G$.

I was trying to prove by induction on $n$ but got stuck:

Base case: $n=2$.

When $n=2$ then $\delta$ is either 1 or 0.
If $\delta=0$ we get that $G$ is a graph with no edges then $|E(G)|= 0 = \delta(n-1)$. When $\delta=1$ $G$ has one edge then $|E(G)| = 1 = \delta(n-1)$. In both cases since $G$ is a subgraph of $G$ the statement hold.

Induction step: Let $n\in N$ such that the statement holds we shall prove for $n+1$:

if $\delta = 0$ then the trival graph with $n+1$ vertices and $0$ edges satisfies the statement. Then lets assume $1\le \delta$ then exist $v \in V$ such that $\deg(v) = \delta$. Lets define $V'=V-{v}$, and define the following spanned subgraph $G'= G[V']$.

Now I understand I need to divide into two cases where $\delta(G')$ is more than $\delta$ and when its less than $\delta$ I am just not sure how to proof either, I understand when $\delta < \delta(G')$ I need to delete edges till I get an equallity of degrees I am just not sure why the reuslt is a spanning graph, on the other case I have no idea how to procced...
... any hint or sketch of the proof would be helpful!

Comment: It seems to me that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808241/graph-theory-proof-regarding-simple-graphs) is also your question. Tell me in your question how they differ and why an additional question is required?

Comment: @kabenyuk your correct ima edit my question, I don't undesrtand why am I allowed to just delete edges from G' to get a new spanning graph with minimal degree of $\delta$ in the case where $\delta$ < d(G), and on the other cases I don't understand how to procced...

Comment: Do you want to have a proof of this statement by induction on the number of vertices?

Comment: @kabenyuk
I mostly want to understand how to proof it, if u have any other method it would be helpful!

Comment: I think you should have induction on the number of edges, not the number of vertices.
I think it would be properly if you write under my [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808241), (where induction on the number of edges is actually performed) what confuses you and what you don't understand. Then I will have an opportunity to supplement that proof with additional details.

Comment: @kabenyuk so the induction should be on the number $\delta * (n-1)$ and not n? I will try...

Comment: @kabenyuk mind giving a sketch of a proof? I have been stuck on it for a day...

Comment: You are right, the induction on the number of vertices works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that induction on the number of vertices is not the best option for this problem. Induction by the number of edges is another matter. But in my opinion, it's better to reason like this.

So, let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and minimal degree $\delta=\delta(G)$. Prove that in $G$ there exists a subgraph $H$ such that $\delta(H)=\delta(G)$ and $E(H)|\leq\delta(n-1)$.

We consider that $n\geq2$ and $\delta\geq1$.

1. Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of subgraphs of $G$ whose minimal degree is equal to $\delta$.
   Since $G\in\mathcal{S}$, $S\neq\varnothing$.
2. Let $H\in\mathcal{S}$ have the smallest number of edges.
3. Let $X$ be all vertices of degree $\delta$ in $H$, $Y$ all vertices of degree $>\delta$
   (we do not exclude that $Y$ can be an empty set, but $X\ne\varnothing$).
   Clearly, $X\cup Y=V(H)$.
4. $Y$ has no edges.
   If $e=y_1y_2\in E(H)$ and $y_1,y_2\in Y$, then $H-e\in\mathcal{S}$ and $|E(H-e)|>|E(H)|$.
   Contradiction.
5. It follows from (4), that
   sum
   $$
   \sum_{x\in X}\deg(x)
   $$
   counts all edges of $H$ (twice edges both vertices of which lie in $X$).
   Hence
   $$
   |E(H)|\leq\sum_{x\in X}\deg(x)=\delta|X|.
   $$
6. If $|X|<n$, then $|X|\leq(n-1)$ and $|E(H)|\leq\delta|X|\leq\delta(n-1)$ as required.
7. If $|X|=n$, then $|E(H)|=\delta n/2\leq\delta(n-1)$. That's it.

**P.S.**

I take it back.
Induction by the number of vertices works well too, but you need to prove a slightly stronger statement.
First one notation, $n_d(G)$ is the number of vertices of degree $d$ in $G$.
Our new statement is formulated as follows.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and minimal degree $\delta=\delta(G)$.
There exists a subgraph $H$ in $G$  such that
$$
\delta(H)=\delta(G),\ n_\delta(H)=n_\delta(G),\text{ and }E(H)|\leq\delta(n-1).
$$

*Proof.* The induction basis $n=1,2$ and the cases $\delta=0$ and arbitrary $n$ are trivial.
Let our statement be true for all graphs of order less than $n$ and $\delta \geq1$.

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and $v\in V(G)$, $\deg(v)=\delta$.
It is clear that $\delta(G-v)\geq\delta-1$.

If $\delta(G-v)=\delta$, then induction works and everything is clear.

If $\delta(G-v)=\delta-1$, then $n_\delta(G-v)\leq\delta$.
By induction, there exists a subgraph $H$ in graph $G-v$ such that

(i) $\delta(H)=\delta(G-v)$,

(ii) $n_{\delta-1}(H)=n_{\delta-1}(G-v)\leq\delta$, and

(iii) $|E(H)|\leq\delta(n-2)$.

Now, to obtain from $H$ a subgraph $F$ of minimal degree $\delta$, we have to add to $H$ at most $\delta$ edges of the graph $G$ (each vertex of degree $\delta-1$ requires at most one edge, in total at most $n_{\delta-1}(H)$ edges).
Therefore, $\delta(F)=\delta$ and
$$
|E(F)|\leq|E(H)|+\delta\leq\delta(n-2)+\delta=\delta(n-1).
$$

Comment: Damn thats more than I expected I really appercite that bro, you have helped me al ot understanding a topic I suck at...